# Need one help to fix one TCL script which is converting one file into another

Tags: regex, bash, shell, tcl, tclsh

I have one TCL script. Input of this tcl script is one .txt file(which is basically log file) and output is config file.
Means this script is converting .txt file into .config file.

Below is the tcl script:

```
set script "[file tail [info script]]"
array set arg $argv;

if { $argc != 4 } {
    puts "The $script script requires two switches.";
    puts "For example, tclsh $script -i st.log -o st.cfg";
    puts "Please try again.";
    exit 2;
}

foreach key [array names arg] {
    set key [string range $key 1 end];
    switch $key {
        "i" {
            set if $arg(-$key);
            set x [catch {set ifid [open $if r]}];
        }
        "o" {
            set of $arg(-$key);
            set x [catch {set ofid [open $of w+]}];
        }
    }
}

while {[gets $ifid line] >= 0} {
    #puts $line;
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+MT_DEBG:\s+STEP\s+\#\s+:\s+(\d+)$} $line matched mtStep] {
set currentMtStep $mtStep;
puts $currentMtStep;
    }
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+MT_DEBG:\s+MKS\s+:\s+(\S+)$} $line matched mtMask] {
array set arrMtMask [list $mtStep $mtMask];
puts $mtMask;
puts $arrMtMask($mtStep);
    }
    if [regexp {\#\#\s+MKS.*MT_DEBG:\s+STEP\s+\#\s+:\s(\S+)$} $line matched mtMaskStep] {
set currentMtMask $arrMtMask($mtMaskStep);
    }
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+SCK_DEBG:\s+STEP\s+\#\s+:\s+(\d+)$} $line matched sckStep] {
if [info exist currentMtStep] {
set currentMtMask $arrMtMask($currentMtStep);
        }
set currentSckStep $sckStep;
#puts $currentSckStep;
    }
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+SCK_DEBG:\s+LOAD_NOP\s+\(\s+(\d+)\s+\)} $line matched sckNOP] {
set currentSckNOP $sckNOP;
puts $ofid "RUNTEST $currentSckNOP";
    }

    if [regexp {\/\/\s+SCK_DEBG:\s+TDI\s+:\s+(\d+)'b(\S+)$} $line matched sckTDILength sckTDI] {
set currentSckTDILength $sckTDILength;
set currentSckTDI $sckTDI;
#puts "$currentSckTDILength $currentSckTDI";
    }
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+SCK_DEBG:\s+TDO\s+:\s+(\d+)'b(\S+)$} $line matched sckTDOLength sckTDO] {
set currentSckTDO $sckTDO;
set currentSckTDOLength $sckTDOLength;
#puts $currentSckTDO;
    }
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+SCK_DEBG:\s+LOAD_IR\s+\(\s+(\d+)\s+,\s+\S+\s+\)} $line matched sckIR] {
set currentSckIR $sckIR;
switch $currentSckTDI {
         "1000" {set op 8; set jtagInstruction "ATPG_CLOCK_CFG";}
         "1010" {set op a; set jtagInstruction "SCK_CORESEL";}
         "110001" {set op 31; set jtagInstruction "MBIST_CFG";}
         "110011" {set op 33; set jtagInstruction "MBIST_SIF_SHIFT";}
         "110110" {set op 36; set jtagInstruction "PLL_CFG";}
         "111110" {set op 3E; set jtagInstruction "MREPAIR_CMD";}
         "1100001" {set op 61; set jtagInstruction "SERDES_CFG";}
         "1100010" {set op 62; set jtagInstruction "SERDES_ITCP";}
         "1100011" {set op 63; set jtagInstruction "MBIST_STATUS";}
         "1100101" {set op 65; set jtagInstruction "TCK_CTRL";}
         "1100110" {set op 66; set jtagInstruction "TEST_CFG";}
         "1100111" {set op 67; set jtagInstruction "TS0_CFG";}
         "1101000" {set op 68; set jtagInstruction "TS0_DATA";}
         "1101001" {set op 69; set jtagInstruction "TS1_CFG";}
         "1101010" {set op 6A; set jtagInstruction "TS1_DATA";}
         "1101011" {set op 6B; set jtagInstruction "USERCODE";}
         "1101100" {set op 6C; set jtagInstruction "VS0_CFG";}
         "1101101" {set op 6D; set jtagInstruction "VS0_DATA";}
         "1101110" {set op 6E; set jtagInstruction "VS1_CFG";}
         "1101111" {set op 6F; set jtagInstruction "VS1_DATA";}
         default {set jtagInstruction "UNKNOWN_INSTRUCTION"}
         }
puts $ofid "INSTR    $jtagInstruction  $currentSckTDILength'b$currentSckTDI";

    }
    if [regexp {\/\/\s+SCK_DEBG:\s+LOAD_DR\s+\(\s+(\d+)\s+,\s+\S+\s+\)} $line matched sckDR] {
set currentSckDR $sckDR;
if { $currentSckTDOLength !=$currentSckTDILength } {
   puts "Error: TDOLength != TDILength";
   exit 2;
}

puts $ofid "SHIFTDR $currentSckTDILength \{"

if ![info exist currentMtMask] {
   puts $ofid "  SCK_STEP_$currentSckStep $currentSckTDILength $currentSckTDILength'b$currentSckTDI ( $currentSckTDOLength'b$currentSckTDO )";
} else {
################################################
   set lengthMtMask [string length $currentMtMask];
   if {$currentSckTDOLength != $lengthMtMask} {
puts "Error: MtMask != TDOLength";
exit 2;
   }
   set lengthTDI [string length $currentSckTDI];
   set lengthTDO [string length $currentSckTDO];
   if {$lengthTDI != $currentSckTDILength} {
puts "STEP $currentSckStep lengthTDI = $lengthTDI"
   }
   if {$lengthTDO != $currentSckTDOLength} {
puts "STEP $currentSckStep lengthTDO = $lengthTDO"
   }
   set patch "";
   for {set i $currentSckTDILength} {$i > $lengthTDI} {incr i -1} {
set patch ${patch}0;
   }
   set currentSckTDI ${patch}${currentSckTDI};
   set patch "";
   for {set i $currentSckTDOLength} {$i > $lengthTDO} {incr i -1} {
set patch ${patch}x;
   }
   set currentSckTDO ${patch}${currentSckTDO};

   set maskedTDO "";
   for {set i [expr $lengthMtMask -1]} {$i >= 0} {incr i -1} {
set index [expr $lengthMtMask -$i -1];
set maskBit [string range $currentMtMask $index $index];
if {$maskBit == 1} { 
   set oBit [string range $currentSckTDO $index $index];
} else {
   set oBit x;

}
set maskedTDO ${maskedTDO}${oBit};
   }

   puts $ofid "  SCK_STEP_$currentSckStep $currentSckTDILength $currentSckTDILength'b$currentSckTDI ( $currentSckTDOLength'b$maskedTDO )";
################################################
}

puts $ofid "\}"
    }

}
```

---

Using below command to run above script :

```
tclsh tcl_script -i txt_file -o config_file
```

---

Partial contents of input file (.txt)

```
  tool(64): 10-s01: (c) Copyright 1999-2016 
tool> source nls
tool>  set gui  on
on

// SCK_INFO:  READ_OPERATION  
// SCK_DEBG:  STEP # : 0 
// SCK_DEBG:  LOAD_NOP ( 4001 ) ;


// SCK_DEBG: STEP # : 2  
// SCK_DEBG: TDI  : 4'b0000  
// SCK_DEBG: TDO : 4'b1110  
// SCK_DEBG: LOAD_IR(4 , 4'b1010) ; 


// SCK_DEBG: STEP # : 10  
// SCK_DEBG: TDI  : 4'b0000  
// SCK_DEBG: TDO : 4'b1110  
// SCK_DEBG: LOAD_DR(16 , 4'b1010000010101111) ; 
// SCK_DEBG: MKS : 16'b1111010010110101 


// SCK_DEBG: STEP # : 12  
// SCK_DEBG: TDI  : 4'b0100  
// SCK_DEBG: TDO : 4'b1001  
// SCK_DEBG: LOAD_DR(4 , 4'b1100) ;


// SCK_DEBG: STEP # : 14  
// SCK_DEBG: TDI  : 4'b0001  
// SCK_DEBG: TDO : 4'b1100  
// SCK_DEBG: LOAD_DR(4 , 4'b1011) ;  
// SCK_DEBG: MKS : 4'b1110
```

---

Partial contents of output file(config), it is generated by the script:

```
This is output file..
Run 20
"some text"
SCK_STEP_2 4 4'b1010 ( 4'b1110)  
SCK_STEP_10 4 4'b1100 (4'b1001)    
SCK_STEP_12 4 4'b1100 (4'b1001)   
SCK_STEP_14 4'b1011 (4'b1100)
```

---

Now issue is, this tcl script is converting txt file into config file without any errors if "SCK_DEBG: MKS" is not present for particular step.

Ideally if "SCK_DEBG: MKS" is present then script should use MKS bit in the last bracket. 
For example: SCK_STEP_14 has MKS so for it correct output should be:

```
 SCK_STEP_14 4'b1011 (4'b1110)
```

But instead of that script is giving below output in the output file.

```
 SCK_STEP_14 4'b1011 (4'b1100)
```

Here, in the last bracket script should use bit from MKS if MKS is present for that particular step , otherwise it should pick TDO bit.
But here in all the cases script is picking TDO bit only.

...
I have tried below stuff to make this script work, but still it is not working:
In the script, 3 "if" statements are present for MT_DEBG, in my txt file MT_DEBG is not present, instead of that SCK_DEBG is present so I have replaced it , but it doesn't worked.
Then syntax like MKS.*MT_DEBG or MKS.*SKC_DEBG is not at all present in my txt so I have commented this "if" statement and re-ran the script. But still it is not working.

I got this txt to config file convert script from my senior. But he is not available now, so that is why writing here.

Someone please help me on this as I am in the initial stage of TCL.

Comment: wait a minute... expected result is exactly the same as output?? `SCK_STEP_14 4'b1011 (4'b1100)` is equal to `SCK_STEP_14 4'b1011 (4'b1110) `? or what is the difference?

Comment: @J. Chomel: difference is there... see the bits in last bracket... expected is (4'b1110) but currently getting output (4'b1100) as output. For Step 14, I should get bit of MKS in that last bracket which is expected, but instead of that I am getting TDO's bit.. did you get it? Or should I explain more? 
If you have any clue on this then please help me.

Comment: Thats a lot of code and data. Can't  you boil this down to a smaller test case? Good luck.

Comment: Agree, too much code. You're asking us to debug your code for you. This is not what stackoverflow is about. Rethink your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @glennjackman , this is the script guys. It cant be reduced and I feel it is not big. and input .txt file is also very small. To debug we just need to copy this script in some file as it is.
I feel the issue is only with those 3 "if" statements for "MT_DEBG" .
I am trying to understand it and debug but not able to do as I am in very initial stage of TCL. Please help me on this to debug. It would be really helpful.

Comment: @PeterLewerin do you have idea on this?

Comment: I run your script, with the input you posted, but had to change it to have some results. Anyway as far as I can understand you're comparing *STEP 10* input with *STEP 14* output.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini: no dude. I am not comparing Step_10 input with step_14 output. Script is generating output file. I am comparing TDO and MKS for the steps which is having MKS value in the input file. Script should compare TDO and MKS and then at whatever places "1" is there in MKS bit, script should replace TDO's same bit with "x" and wherever places "0" is there in MKS , for that same place TDO bit should remain as it is... did you get this? I know this is confusing, but please help me if possible. I will really appreciate it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @KinskiOjnkn that could not happen because, you never catch the *currentMtMask*. Place a *puts* instruction after line 98 where you have the *if ![info exist currentMtMask]* to see this. The input you provide miss a line that start with *##* instead of *//*, check the relative regexps.